# Can I pass a JSON object from Silverlight to javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, json, silverlight-3.0

I know I can call javascript and pass string values from Silverlight, but can I pass a JSON object or does it have to be serialized?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the object have `[ScriptableType]` and pass it in your arguments, you can achieve what you're trying to do without encoding the object to JSON and decoding on the JS side:

See the heading **Return Objects From Silverlight Method Calls To JavaScript** at http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/06/19/Silverlight-and-JavaScript-Interop-Basics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The full answer to this question can be found at:

[Silverlight passing JSON object incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295859/silverlight-passing-json-object-incorrectly)