# Silverlight passing JSON object incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, json, serialization, silverlight-3.0

I have a Silverlight class marked with the ScriptableType & ScriptableMember and I expect to be able to pass the object from Silverlight to javascript. When I call JSON.stringify (in javascript) I expect to receive a JSON representation of the object but all I get is `{}`

The class is defined as:

```
[ScriptableType()]
public class MyEvent
{
    [ScriptableMember(ScriptAlias = "eventContent")]
    public int EventContent { get; set; }
}
```

I pass the object from Silverlight like this:

```
  var jsonObject = new MyEvent { EventContent = 1 };
  HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("publishValue", topic, jsonObject);
```

And in javascript I'm doing the following:

```
 alert(topic);
 alert(jsonObject);
 alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

When I use the debugger I only see the `jsonObject` as of type `Object` but the call `alert(jsonObject)` returns the correct type and if I access the property `jsonObject.eventContent` I get the correct value back, but it doesn't serialize correctly with `JSON.stringify`.

Anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

I don't want to have to serialize the object in Silverlight before sending to javascript.

Cheers

AWC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem!

Instead of declaring an object like this for passing from Silverlight to javascript:

```
[ScriptableType()] 
public class MyEvent 
{ 
    [ScriptableMember(ScriptAlias = "eventContent")] 
    public int EventContent { get; set; } 
}
```

I use the `System.Json` namepsace and create a `JsonObject` like this:

```
  var ob = new JsonObject
  {
       {"eventContent", 1}
  };
```

Check out the documentation of `System.Json.JsonObject` for more info.

Cheers

AWC

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify` enumerates over enumerable properties of an object using `for...in`.  If the properties aren't enumerable, they won't be included in the resulting string.

The Silverlight object is an external object, not a native javascript object.  Just like an ActiveXObject, the properties are not discoverable/enumerable.  I'm not sure if there's a way around this.  A couple of pages I found hint towards implementing IEnumerable to be able to iterate using a `foreach` in the native language but I'm not sure if this would carry over to JavaScript.

I wouldn't rely on it being possible but you never know.  If you require an object to be enumerable, the only way might be to serialize it using `System.Json` and call `eval` on the document to unserialize it in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, serializing in SL and deserializing in JS is how I've got round the problem

Comment: System.Json seems to be not available in SIlverLight 4.